# Is $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ or only around $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that for all $x\in\mathbb R$,
$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}.$$

I know that around $0$, we have that $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n),$$
it's the Taylor expansion. I was wondering if the previous formula is also true for all $x\in\mathbb R$ or only around $0$ ?

Comment: It's true for all $x\in\mathbb R$, but the fact that the rest is $o(x^n)$ is not useful if you are not in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: The error $O(x^n)$ is not very usefull when checking around $x>1$ since your error is way too big to use it.

Comment: For your little-o, do you mean as $x \to 0$, the usual meaning?  Or do you mean as $n \to \infty$ ?  In the first case, your question makes no sense.  For the second case, we actually have $o(1)$,  which is much better than $o(x^n)$ when $|x| \ge 1$.

Comment: @Surb Are you sure about that?

Comment: @MSE Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

The statement
$$\tag{1}\exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} + o(x^n)$$
can not be true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, because $\exp(x)$ is increasing faster than any polnomial, i.e. we have
$$\frac{\exp(x)}{x^n} \rightarrow \infty \quad \text{for} \ x \rightarrow \infty.$$
On the other hand, (1) would imply
$$\frac{\exp(x)}{x^n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{n!} \quad \text{for} \ x \rightarrow \infty.$$
That's nonsense!

Comment: I fully agree! (+1)

Comment: The notation $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n)$ is correct for all $x\in\mathbb R$. To me it mean : there is a function $R:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t. $e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}+R(x)$ where $\lim_{x\to 0}x^n R(x)=0$. The only thing is that the function $R$ won't give us any information of the behavior of the function $x\longmapsto e^x$ at for example the neighborhood of $x=2$ (or at any other point $x\neq 0$). It's only relevant at the neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: The meaning of the Landau notation depends on the context! For example, $f \in o(g)$ in $a$ can also mean that $|f(x)| \leq C |g(x)|$ and $|f(x)|/|g(x)| \rightarrow 0$. Asking (1) for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is not useful in the usal definition, as one find e.g. in Wikipedia, where we fix some point $a$ and analyze the behaviour $x \rightarrow a$. That is only a local property, as you already noted.

Answer (score 1):

With reference with the little-o notation used recall that as $x\to x_0$

$$f(x)=o(g(x)) \iff f(x)=\omega(x)\cdot g(x)\quad \omega(x) \to 0 \implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$$

then

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n)$$

is a correct notation only for $x\to 0$.

Comment: @Surb Please add a full answer with an explanation of that. Thanks

Comment: The notation $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n)$ is correct for all $x\in\mathbb R$. To me it mean : there is a function $R:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t. $e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}+R(x)$ where $\lim_{x\to 0}x^n R(x)=0$. The only thing is that the function $R$ won't give us any information of the behavior of the function $x\longmapsto e^x$ at for example the neighborhood of $x=2$ (or at any other point $x\neq 0$). It's only relevant at the neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: @Surb The problem to me is with the little-o notation, since it becomes menaingless for $x\to x_0\neq 0$.

Comment: It's indeed true that we won't have any information when $x\to x_0\neq 0$. But here for example, set $R(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$. Then $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+R(x),$$ is true for all $x\in\mathbb R$, and moreover $R(x)=o(x^n)$. So the notation $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n)$ make sense for all $x\in\mathbb R$ but it's relevant only when $x\to 0$.

Comment: But $$R(x)/x^n \not \to 0$$ as $x\to x_0\neq 0$, it seems an uncorrect use of littele-o notetion to me.

Comment: I see what you mean. I attribute the notation $f(x)=o(x-a)$ when $x\to a$. Indeed, without this convention, we have to precise it. Maybe $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+\underset{x=0}{o}(x^n)$$ is true for all $x\in\mathbb R$ would be more appropriate. The OP should give more precision on the notation. But indeed, without more precision, you are true.